# How to exit from find -exec if it fails on one of the files

Tags: bash, find, exec, exit

I want to run the command

```
find some/path -exec program \{} \;
```

but I want the find command to quit as soon as the command

```
program \{}
```

fails on any of the files found.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62880/how-to-stop-the-find-command-after-first-match

Answer (score 17):

I think it is not possible to achieve what you want, only with `find -exec`.

The closest alternative would be to do pipe `find` to `xargs`, like this:

```
find some/path -print0 | xargs -0 program
```

or

```
find some/path -print0 | xargs -0L1 program
```

This will quit if program terminates with a non-zero exit status

- the `print0` is used so that files with newlines in their names can be handled
- `-0` is necessary when `-print0` is used
- the `L1` tells `xargs` program to execute program with one argument at a time (default is to add all arguments in a single execution of program)

If you only have sane file names, you can simplify like this:

```
find some/path | xargs program
```

or

```
find some/path | xargs -L1 program
```

Finally, If program takes more than one argument, you can use `-i` combined with `{}`. E.g.

```
find some/path | xargs -i program param1 param2 {} param4
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other fine answers, GNU find (at least) has a `-quit` predicate:

```
find path -other -predicates \( -exec cmd {} \; -o -quit \)
```

The `-quit` predicate is [certainly non-standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) and does not exist in BSD find.

Comment: This is close to what I need but I need to exit with a nonzero exit status if this fails (the second part of the predicate).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my example for a "build system", which stops after hitting the first compiler error
(based on Kojiro's answer, which did not exaclty work for me):

(The need for escaped parentheses is real. I know that hurts.)

```
find -name '*.cpp' \( -print -a -exec g++ -c {} \; -o -quit \)
```

I want to build a static library of basically all C++ files located in the current directory and below.

Before running the compiler I want to have the file `-print`-ed, then `-exec`-ed, but when it fails (and leaves errors on `stderr`, it should `-quit`.

`-a` is like `&&` and `-o` is like `||` in shell or C.

Without the parentheses, GNU find "optimizes" the query, by trying the most probable condition first, which is -- I guess -- `-quit`.

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe the output from `find` to another subprocess and use `while`/`break`:

```
find some/path | while read f
do
    program $f
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: It would be better to just do `if ! program $f; then break …`. You could also delimit across NUL instead of newlines using `-print0` and read -d'', which is safer.

Comment: This variant apply safety suggestions from @kojiro, which are important if files contain spaces. For that you also need quotes around the `$f`. (and note it uses bash-specific `$''`). It's smaller too: `find path -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f; do command "$f" || break; done`

Answer (score 0):

```
% _find_trap() {
>   _find_pid="${1}" ; _find_ops="${2}" ; _find_trigger="${3}"
>   shift 3 && set -- "${@}" 
>   trap 'kill -s INT "-${_find_pid}" \
>     unset _find_pid _find_ops _find_trigger ; set - \
>     1>&2 printf "%s" "find killed due to trap" \
>     exit [CODE] ' TRAP
>  while { sh -c "${_find_ops} ${@}"} {
>    [ "${_find_trigger}" ] && { kill -s TRAP "-${_find_pid}" ; break ; }
>    ...
>  }
> export -f _find_trap ; find . -execdir _find_trap \"$$\" \"${cmds}\" \
>   \"${testable_trigger}\" "{}" +
```